# Express route setup with NGINX and HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

In short: I have the same problem as previously asked and answered within this question([How to setup routes with Express and NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668559/how-to-setup-routes-with-express-and-nginx)) although my files look slightly different since I'm using HTTPS and I never made use of `try_files`.

*The normal root link works (my.website.org), but when I navigate to (my.website.com/login), I get a 404 from NGINX*

The sites by themselves all work perfectly fine (also when I switch out the index for the login), but as soon as I am not accessing the root link i receive the 404 :(. I already tried a couple of suggested solutions but somehow couldn't make any work for me. Maybe someone on here has a suggestion regarding my setup.

---

Filestructure of my project:

```
my
| - public
| - views
|     | - index.pug
|     L - login.pug
| - app.js
L - package.json
```

---

First up my **app.js** file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// Load View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Home Route
app.get('/', function(req, res){res.render('index');});
// Login Route
app.get('/login', function(req, res){res.render('login');});

// Start Server
app.listen(3000, function(){console.log('Server started on port 3000...');});
```

---

Next my NGINX Configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.website.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my.website.org;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/my.error.log;

    location = / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root /var/www/my/public;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    ssl_certificate /myfullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /mykey.pem;
}
```

Comment: You have no location to process `/login`. Try changing `location = / {` to `location / {`.

Comment: Oh my god ... I feel quite ashamed now, since that mistake took me quite some time today xD Thank you very much, that obviously fixed my issue <3